# What is the preferred Bash shebang ("#!")?

Tags: bash, shebang

Is there any `Bash` shebang objectively better than the others for most uses?

- `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
- `#!/bin/bash`
- `#!/bin/sh`
- `#!/bin/sh -`
- etc

I vaguely recall a long time ago hearing that adding a dash to the end prevents someone passing a command to your script, but can’t find any details on that.

Comment: And its `/usr/local/bin/bash` on OpenBSD.

Comment: Adding the dash is meant to prevent a certain kind of setuid root spoofing attacks, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45490/what-is-setuid-based-script-root-spoofing?newreg=e1ab392777f44bd8bf57e33def375cf4

Comment: I would upvote this, but it has a score of 1337 and I don't want to disturb it!

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` poses a privilege escalation security threat when a suid program executes a bash script that has such a shebang. The user can simply manipulate his `PATH` and get an arbitrary bash executable to be run instead, with elevated privileges.

Comment: Stumbled upon a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612980/why-is-usr-bin-env-bash-superior-to-bin-bash

Comment: Note that the answer is very dependent on whether or not your script actually needs to be a *bash* script (relying on `bash` extensions) or if any (POSIX) `sh` would do.

Answer (score 2051):

You should use **`#!/usr/bin/env bash`** for [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability): Different *nixes put `bash` in different places, and using `/usr/bin/env` is a workaround to run the first `bash` found on the `PATH`.

And **[`sh` is not `bash`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts)**.

Comment: Thanks.  Also looks like adding - to the end of $!/usr/bin/env bash - won't do anything since only one argument is allowed by *nix in the shebang, and that is used by 'bash'.  That's apparently only useful for preventing malicious arguments being passed to the script on the commandline if the script's shebang is one of the others with no arguments (`/bin/sh`, etc).

Comment: Why not `#!/bin/bash`? Does this depend on whether the user has correct `path` defined?

Comment: @Ray `bash` doesn't live in `/bin` on all systems.

Comment: ^^ Windows Git Bash path is */user/bin/bash*, but my Siteground hosting path is */bin/bash* (checked with `echo $SHELL`).

Comment: Same for me, I just added it to an alias: `alias shebang='echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash"'`, now I just have to open the terminal and type shebang instead of going here.

Comment: This answer is deceptive.  POSIX does not say that `env` is at `/usr/bin/env`.  It could be at `/bin/env` or anywhere in fact, as long as it is in the path.  It could be at `/dummy/env` if `/dummy` is in `PATH`.  Shebang itself is undefined under POSIX, so I could make `#!stop toaster` start the USB coffee machine and be POSIX compliant. So `#!/usr/bin/env bash` isn't particularly better than `#!/bin/bash`, it could be less portable depending.

Comment: @darkfeline Portability isn't absolute - it is mathematically impossible to make any script that will do the same thing on every platform. As of 2012 through 2018 `/usr/bin/env` exists on more machines than either of `/bin/bash` xor `/usr/bin/bash`, so a script that starts with this line will *do the expected thing on as many machines as possible.*

Comment: @I0b0 It will do the expected thing *if I have the right version in my path*. I can't specify that my script needs `bash` 4.2 or later using a shebang; I can only document that requirement. Really, the script writer shouldn't be the one in control of the shebang; it should be the person *running* the script. Python does this well, IMO: scripts use `#!python`, and the installer replaces it with the correct shebang for the target system.

Comment: @l0b0 Actually, portability can be absolute under POSIX.  Assuming of course that Bash is in the path, you can use a script like [this](https://gist.github.com/darkfeline/19a91aa9e59259bb61e4614a32091600).  An executable file without a shebang and not matching an binary executable format is run with sh.  This is fully portable under POSIX, unlike this answer.  (Sorry for double comment, stupid StackOverflow comment editing.)

Comment: @chepner The shebang line is IMO the wrong place to ensure that you're running a specific version; that's easily done by checking `BASH_VERSINFO`.

Comment: @Oylex Thanks for the awesome idea :-) I slightly changed it to copy to macos paste-board `alias shebang='echo "#!/usr/bin/env bash" | pbcopy'`

Comment: @darkfeline That’s a cute trick but it *still* doesn’t do “the right thing”. It will execute *a* bash but not necessarily the *desired* bash. Case in point, on macOS `/bin/sh` is bash, but it’s a woefully outdated bash, and power users usually install a modern bash into a different location. But your script will always run `/bin/sh` on macOS, never the user’s preferred bash. By contrast, this answer works just fine on macOS.

Comment: @KonradRudolph if you're referring to [this](https://gist.github.com/darkfeline/19a91aa9e59259bb61e4614a32091600), then assuming that `bash` in your `PATH` is the right Bash, yes, it will run Bash.  If it's not the right Bash, then `#!/usr/bin/env bash` won't work either.  It sounds like you didn't see the `exec bash` line, which naturally execs bash, not `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @darkfeline No, it won’t run the right bash because the `if` branch will never be taken, because `BASH_VERSION` is set by `/bin/sh` on macOS (which is what will run this script if you execute it in a shell or via a system call). As a consequence, the script will never `exec bash`.

Comment: Then you can just check the `BASH_VERSION` to make sure you're not using the super old version?

Comment: @Eric The only security concern with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is if the user is able to invoke the script with something like `-i` as the zeroth argument, and they're otherwise successfully disallowed from starting an interactive shell. But script files themselves should never have the SUID bit set anyway (because that has other inherent insecurities), and once we exclude those, the security concern is approximately zero (if you are already thoroughly preventing a piece of code from doing something as the user it already runs as, it can be prevented from doing (that thing through) `bash -i` too).

Comment: @mtraceur you're saying that if security measures are applied then the system is secure, so we should never care about those cases. Well you're wrong: good security practices precisely account for cases where someone made a mistake. For example why do we even have administrator privilege if all that is needed is for normal users to know he should never run some commands that may give him access to private information or gain control of the system?

Comment: @Eric That's not what I'm saying, and I'm not wrong. `#!/usr/bin/env` is *not* insecure in any real way, because any configuration where eliminating it raises security is necessarily already *so utterly insecure* that it is still utterly insecure even without `#!/usr/bin/env`. At the same time, `#!/usr/bin/env` is extremely useful for certain goals, so your vague claim of "security concerns" (vague to the point that it is indistinguishable from cargo-culting/superstition) is likely to do more real harm than `#!/usr/bin/env` ever will.

Comment: On further thought, I do see a real security concern: if a `#!/usr/bin/env` script is invoked with elevated privileges with an unsanitized `PATH`. Of course, SUID/SGID shouldn't be set on scripts for other reasons, SUID/SGID on scripts is deliberately disabled by default on most modern systems, and SUID/SGID programs should be sanitizing/resetting `PATH` if they're going to use it to invoke other programs. But yes, if you have a secure script which is SUID/SGID or is called by an SUID/SGID program which never calls programs through the `PATH` it inherits, then `#!/usr/bin/env` adds insecurity.

Comment: yes indeed @mtraceur, `/usr/bin/env` adds a level of indirection which is certainly convenient, but can also be exploited if the right -- albeit rare -- conditions are also met.

Comment: @l0b0 if env must always be in the system path, then can you just use `#!env bash`?

Comment: @bgibson Interesting question, but no, the first command must be an absolute path. Otherwise we wouldn't need this workaround, and the shebang line could just have been `#!bash`.

Answer (score 244):

On most but not all systems, I recommend using:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It's not 100% portable (some systems place `bash` in a location other than `/bin`), but the fact that a lot of existing scripts use `#!/bin/bash` pressures various operating systems to make `/bin/bash` at least a symlink to the main location.

The alternative of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

has been suggested -- but there's no guarantee that the `env` command is in `/usr/bin` (and I've used systems where it isn't). Furthermore, this form will use the first instance of `bash` in the current user's `$PATH`, which might not be a suitable version of the Bash shell.

(But `/usr/bin/env` should work on any reasonably modern system, either because `env` is in `/usr/bin` or because the system does something to make it work. The system I referred to above was SunOS 4, which I probably haven't used in about 25 years.)

If you need a script to run on a system that doesn't have `/bin/bash`, you can modify the script to point to the correct location (that's admittedly inconvenient).

I've discussed the tradeoffs in greater depth in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454).

A somewhat obscure update: One system I use, [Termux](https://termux.com/), a desktop-Linux-like layer that runs under Android, doesn't have `/bin/bash` (`bash` is `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash`) -- but it has special handling to support `#!/bin/bash`.

UPDATE: As Edward L. points out in a comment, bash is not part of the "base OS" on FreeBSD, and even if it's installed by default, it probably won't be installed as `/bin/bash`. On such a system, you can either use the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick (I'm assuming that FreeBSD installed `env` as `/usr/bin/env`), or you can use the path where bash is installed (apparently that's `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`). If your scripts are only intended to run under FreeBSD, you can use `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`. If they're meant to be portable, you can use the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick (which has some disadvantages; see my answer cited above) or you can update the `#!` line when you install your scripts.

There may well be similar issues on some other operating systems.

Comment: 2-years later and this is still the best advice here. If the simple solution doesn't work then you've got to question your earlier decisions. The accepted and most upvoted answer isn't wrong, it's just not right :)

Comment: Termux has special handling for `#/use/bin/env` too, right?

Comment: @mtraceur Yes, it does -- and I just discovered that the special handling works on the command line, not just on a `#!` line.

Answer (score 95):

`/bin/sh` is usually a link to the system's default shell, which is often `bash` but on, e.g., Debian systems is the lighter weight `dash`.  Either way, the original Bourne shell is `sh`, so if your script uses some `bash` (2nd generation, "Bourne Again sh") specific features (`[[ ]]` tests, arrays, various sugary things, etc.), then you should be more specific and use the later. This way, on systems where bash is not installed, your script won't run. I understand there may be an exciting trilogy of films about this evolution...but that could be hearsay.

Also note that when evoked as `sh`, `bash` to some extent [behaves as POSIX standard](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour) `sh` (see also [the GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) about this).

Comment: The Public Domain Korn Shell (pdksh) is default on OpenBSD.

Comment: Most systems will *not* link `/bin/sh` to anywhere in `/usr` as that would make it rather hard for the init scripts to run before `/usr` is mounted.

Comment: @aij I don't know why I put "many or most" there -- I'm a fedora user, where `/bin` and `/sbin` for years have just been symlinks by default, to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`, so in that context `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash` and the actual directory is `/usr/bin`.  But I'll correct the above.

Answer (score 37):

Using a shebang line to invoke the appropriate interpreter is not just for BASH. You can use the shebang for any interpreted language on your system such as Perl, Python, PHP (CLI) and many others. By the way, the shebang

```
#!/bin/sh -
```

(it can also be two dashes, i.e. `--`) ends bash options everything after will be treated as filenames and arguments.

Using the `env` command makes your script portable and allows you to setup custom environments for your script hence portable scripts should use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Or for whatever the language such as for Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Be sure to look at the `man` pages for `bash`:

```
man bash
```

and `env`:

```
man env
```

Note: On Debian and Debian-based systems, like Ubuntu, `sh` is linked to `dash` not `bash`. As all system scripts use `sh`. This allows bash to grow and the system to stay stable, according to Debian.

Also, to keep invocation *nix like I never use file extensions on shebang invoked scripts, as you cannot omit the extension on invocation on executables as you can on Windows. The file command can identify it as a script.

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on how you write your bash scripts. If your `/bin/sh` is symlinked to bash, when bash is invoked as `sh`, [some features are unavailable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode).

If you want bash-specific, non-POSIX features, use `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Bash is not installed on OpenBSD. If you install it via `pkg_add`, then its located in `/usr/local/bin`, which may not be on-path.

Comment: how about a `POSIX` feature?

Answer (score 2):

If portable includes "runs on alpine linux" which *does not have bash installed*, use `#!/bin/sh`,  and do not specify bash explicitly. And keep your scripts POSIX compatible instead of depending on bash extensions. The number of places that now run alpine linux vastly outnumbers the rare weird systems where `#!/bin/sh` does not work.

On ubuntu and on alpine, this will run on some variation of ash. Which also means that you are less likely to be affected by bash-related security vulnerabilities such as shellshock than if you were running on top of bash. Bash is widely used but its internal implementation is terrible, and explicitly specifying it as the shell used instead of relying on the system to pick the shell is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

`#!/bin/sh`

as most scripts do not need specific bash feature and should be written for sh.

Also, this makes scripts work on the BSDs, which do not have bash per default.

Comment: But the question is what to use for Bash scripts specifically. This has the distinct and potentially serious drawback that it will not work for Bash scripts (i.e. anything which uses Bash-only features). This is a common pitfall for newbies. See also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: @Eric Yes, but as *@tripleee* says, it's not a good choice for Bash scripts because the original Bourne shell is missing the features that Bash added.

Comment: ...which are not available on systems which do not have Bash available. Which includes the BSDs, but also anything based on busybox, which is a large chunk of anything that runs in a container, both for container size, and for security reasons.