# Bash variables not acting as expected

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script which parses a file line by line, extracts the date using a `cut` command and then makes a folder using that date. However, it seems like my variables are not being populated properly. Do I have a syntax issue? Any help or direction to external resources is very appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | grep .mp3 | cut -d '.' -f 1 > filestobemoved

cat filestobemoved | while read line

do
    varYear= $line | cut -d '_' -f 3
    varMonth= $line | cut -d '_' -f 4
    varDay= $line | cut -d '_' -f 5

    echo $varMonth
    mkdir $varMonth'_'$varDay'_'$varYear

    cp ./$line'.mp3' ./$varMonth'_'$varDay'_'$varYear/$line'.mp3'  
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) please and thank you.

Comment: For a quick (but horrible) fix: `varYear=$(echo $line | cut -d '_' -f 3)`.

Comment: What is the format of your file names? is it `field1_field2_YYYY_MM_DD.mp3` or `field1_field2_YYYY_MM_DD_someotherstuff.mp3` or could it be both?

Comment: Note that files such as `pink.floyd.the.wall.mp3` will be chopped to `pink` by your first `cut`.  If you have no names with dots before the `.mp3` extension, this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many errors and non-recommended practices in your code. Try the following:

```
for f in *.mp3; do
    f=${f%%.*}
    IFS=_ read _ _ varYear varMonth varDay <<< "$f"
    echo $varMonth
    mkdir -p "${varMonth}_${varDay}_${varYear}"
    cp "$f.mp3" "${varMonth}_${varDay}_${varYear}/$f.mp3"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, your example is working great. Between that and the resources that I0b0 gave me I think I have a much better handle on where to go from here. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**The actual error** is that you need to use [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution). For example, instead of

```
varYear= $line | cut -d '_' -f 3
```

you need to use

```
varYear=$(cut -d '_' -f 3 <<< "$line")
```

A secondary error there is that `$foo | some_command` on its own line does not mean that the contents of `$foo` gets [piped](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes) to the next command as input, but is rather *executed as a command*, and the output of the *command* is passed to the next one.

Some best practices and tips to take into account:

- [Use a portable shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) - `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (disclaimer: That's my answer).
- [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
- Avoid [useless uses of `cat`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html).
- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices)
- Don't use files for temporary storage if you can use pipes. It is literally orders of magnitude faster, and generally makes for simpler code if you want to do it properly.
- If you have to use files for temporary storage, put them in the directory created by `mktemp -d`. Preferably add a [trap](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap) to remove the temporary directory cleanly.
- There's no need for a `var` prefix in variables.
- `grep` searches for basic regular expressions by default, so `.mp3` matches *any single character* followed by the literal string `mp3`. If you want to search for a dot, you need to *either* use `grep -F` to search for literal strings or escape the regular expression as `\.mp3`.
- You generally want to use `read -r` (defined by POSIX) to treat backslashes in the input literally.

Comment: Thanks for the resources, Between you and chenper I think I have a much better understanding of where to. It's greatly appreciated!