# Variable within a Variable in Bash

Tags: bash

Can not figure this out.  Can't figure out the variable within a variable.  Also, how to I silence the output if a host is down.

```
#/bin/bash

for IP in `cat list`; do
        output=$(
        $name=`snmpwalk -v 2c -c snmp2 $IP SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 | grep -o '[^ ]*$'`
        $type=`snmpwalk -v 2c -c snmp2 $IP SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.47.1.1.1.1.13.1 | grep -o '[^ ]*$'`
        $soft=`snmpwalk -v 2c -c snmp2 $IP 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 | grep -i ios | awk -F, '{print $2,$3}'`
        )
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo $IP,echo $output[$name][$type][$soft]
        else
                echo $IP,null
        fi
done
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more info ?

Comment: `output=$(` `$output[$name][$type][$soft]` What is this supposed to be ?

Answer (score 1):

**`$name=value` is wrong. In Bash it's `name=value`.**

The `$name` etc. variables are also declared in a [*subshell*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), so they won't be available in the outside code.

Some other issues with the code:

- It only checks the exit code of the *last* `snmpwalk`. Use `set -o errexit` for your own sanity.
- Use `$(foo)` for command substitutions. `` `foo` `` is obsolete.
- [Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!
- [Useless Use of `cat` award](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) awarded.
- Use a [portable shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) (Disclaimer: My own answer)
- `echo foo,echo bar` will print `foo,echo bar`. `;` is the line separator, but whenever you feel tempted to use it just add a newline for clarity.

Comment: Another issue: `for IP in \`cat list\``.

Comment: Another: `$output[$name][$type][$soft]`

Comment: @Jidder That *could* be intentional, although I doubt it from context.

Comment: @l0b0 Could it ? I thought you could only have 1d arrays in bash ?

Comment: I suspect that it would (if it weren't for all the other syntax and logic errors) print simply the literal consisting of `$output`, a square bracket, `$name`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes to add:

`` `cat list` `` can simply be `$(<list)` and even safer if you could use `while read; do ...; done < list` but that would require that items are separated by newlines.

`output` in `output=$()` would never get any output for value since the assignments within (`name`, `type` and `soft`) already takes them.

**Even if** you properly assign your variables by removing the leading dollar sign (`$`) you would still -not- have any value for them for those assignments happen inside a subshell. After context of `output=$()` ends, those values would be lost so you can expect that `name`, `type` and `soft` would just have an empty value after.