# error in crontab and not in console

Tags: bash

I have a rare problem.

When I execute a file by console, it works well, but when I execute it (the same file) by crontab I receive an error in the following part of the code

```
join -j 1 -t ',' <(sort $dir/Xem3.csv) <(sort $dir/coordenades.csv)|awk -F "," '{print  $15","$16","$17"," $3"," $4","$18"," $5"," $6","$7","$8"," $9","$10","$11","$12","$13}' > $dir/Xem4.csv
```

the error in the log of the crontab is

```
/home/enric/proves/web.sh: line 95: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/enric/proves/web.sh: line 95: `join -j 1 -t ',' <(sort $dir/Xem3.csv) <(sort $dir/coordenades.csv)|awk -F "," '{print  $15","$16","$17"," $3"," $4","$18"," $5"," $6","$7","$8"," $9","$10","$11","$12","$13}' > $dir/Xem4.csv'
```

any idea?

My script is

```
#/bin/bash

dir=/home/enric/proves

join -j 1 -t ',' <(sort $dir/Xem3.csv) <(sort $dir/coordenades.csv)|awk -F "," '{print  $15","$16","$17"," $3"," $4","$18"," $5"," $6","$7","$8"," $9","$10","$11","$12","$13}' > $dir/Xem4.csv

tr -d '\r' < $dir/Xem4.csv > $dir/out.csv
```

Comment: Does your console script specify the shell it's using? E.g. are you sure your crontab is using the same shell as your interactive login?

Comment: Looks like you're using process substitution `<(sort ...)`, a bash feature but your script is either invoked as `sh script.sh` or `./script.sh` with the wrong shebang. It should be `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

Comment: At the top I have #/bin/bash

Comment: @Enric that should be `#!/bin/bash` (with exclamation mark)

Answer (score 2):

Your first line is not a shebang line. You want [`#!/usr/bin/env bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588). Without the exclamation mark the line is just another comment, and the script will be executed in the shell that cron uses (usually `/bin/sh`). [`<(my_command)` is a bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Expansions), hence the syntax error.