# mkdir -p issue while bash scripting

Tags: bash, mkdir

I am attempting to create a recursive directory tree with some nested directories along the way.

While testing this manually in bash it functions without issue. However while testing this command in a bash script it is broken...instead of creating the directory tree, it creates two directories '{dir1,dir2/' and then {subdir1,subdir2},dir3,dir4} inside of the first.

Here is the command:

```
mkdir -p main/{dir1,dir2/{subdir1,subdir2},dir3,dir4}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of creating the directory tree is creates two directorys '{dir1,dir2/' and then '{subdir1,subdir2},dir3,dir4}' inside of the first.

Comment: This executes as expected for me, are you **certain** you are using the same command in both cases? Does the script contain any other commands that might alter this one?

Comment: Same for me. Are you sure you're not running it in `sh`/`dash`?

Comment: Yes I copy and paste the command out of my bash script. The command works manually but not in the script. And yes I am running bash for sure.

Comment: @techno-shaman Run `bash -x yourscript`, post output please

Comment: #!/bin/sh should I use #!/bin/bash?

Comment: @techno-shaman Depends on your system, but generally yes. `#!/bin/sh` is very often `dash`, not `bash`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/3076724) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/141932/234837) for an explenation

Comment: It was the #! I was using. Thanks! This is good to know. I'd been using #!/bin/bash forever but started #!/bin/sh recently because I saw someone else using it. Didn't think it would cause this sort of problem! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Your script is being run by `/bin/sh`, which in your case is not `bash` but rather some Posix-compatible shell, quite possibly dash.

Brace expansion is a shell extension implemented by quite a few shells, including bash, ksh and zsh, but it is not available in dash.

Make sure that your shebang line specifies bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```