# Loop Script Error

Tags: bash

```
while true; do
    java -Xmx512M -jar spigot.jar
    echo 'Press any key to exit...'
    if read -r -N 1 -t 5; then
        break
    fi
done
```

I get this error:

```
./start.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./start.sh: line 7: `done'
```

- I have Bash installed
- This code run fine in another computer

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right shell ? Do you have a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/253056) ?

Comment: How do you start your script? If i run it by my own, it Looks good

Comment: Any chance you copied it from a Windoze machine, and it has weird line endings?

Comment: Are there any weird characters between the `while true;` and the `do`?  I can reproduce your error by omitting the "`do`".

Comment: To make sure you're running the script with bash, either add `#!/bin/bash` as the top line or execute it by sourcing it `. myscript.sh` where myscript.sh is the name of your script

Comment: I use ./start.sh to start my script

Comment: Try running the script with `bash -x start.sh`, that should give a trace of the shell expansions and ensure it is running under bash.

Comment: same result....

Comment: It looks alright, my test omits the java call line and runs fine, like he says use the bash -x test.sh option

Comment: Your code works fine for me (with a dummy command substituted for your `java` command).  I'm therefore inclined to guess that there's something weird about your local copy of the script. @Jack suggests one form that could take.  It's short; how about just rewriting it, in a new file, with a local text editor?

Comment: after re code still not working

Comment: I find out that the problem is the while true; do loop doesn't working,but why?

Comment: do `xxd < script` and post the result in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Most comments are not shown initially. Make it easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out why,because i make that file in a windows computer,the file is msdos format,so it isn't working