# How to run multiple python scripts from shell one after another

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I want to run multiple Python scripts from shell. I used `pythonDim.sh` script to do the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
/home/path_to_script/dimAO.py
/home/path_to_script/dimA1.py
/home/path_to_script/dimA2.py
/home/path_to_script/dimA3.py
```

But it's not working. How to write the shell script?

Comment: That shebang is wrong; although the script may *run* Python scripts, it can't itself be executed as Python.

Comment: use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to run it via a `bash` shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang or any other shebang depending on the shell you want to use

Comment: As mentioned above - change the header to bash and start each line by calling python, for example: `python /home/path_to_script/dimAO.py`

Comment: *I want to run multiple Python scripts from shell* - but your `#!` line says *python*, not a shell.

Comment: is it necessary to add header in python script `dimA0.py`. and is it necessary to make scripts executable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run sequentially:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/path_to_script/dimAO.py
/home/path_to_script/dimA1.py
/home/path_to_script/dimA2.py
/home/path_to_script/dimA3.py
```

To run them all in parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/path_to_script/dimAO.py &
/home/path_to_script/dimA1.py &
/home/path_to_script/dimA2.py &
/home/path_to_script/dimA3.py &
```

Use redirection (> or >>) to redirect stdout and stderr, as desired.

Comment: he should call every python script using `python <path to python file>` and to run in // I would recommend to add `nohup` in order to avoid that by closing your shell it kills all the processes!!!!