# shell terminal: sh file prefix ./

Tags: macos, shell, unix, sh

A beginner unix shell user question:

When I call a sh file in terminal: 
Why do I need to prefix it with self folder and slash: **./** ?

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tells the shell that you want to run a program that exists in your current directory. If that directory already exists in PATH - check with :

```
echo ${PATH}
```

then you don't need to use it and you can drop the ./ part.

Your script also needs to have the x bit set with chmod and the first line must tell the shell what new shell to spawn, see -

[What is the preferred Bash shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang)

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good description of the difference between running `sh script.sh` and just `./script.sh` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136547/what-is-the-difference-between-running-bash-script-sh-and-script-sh).

Hopefully it helps.