# Error when using mpirun with a shell script

Tags: shell, mpi, openmpi

When I run

```
mpirun -np 4 mpi_script.sh
```

I get the error

```
Open MPI tried to fork a new process via the "execve" system call but failed.
...
Error:             Exec format error
```

despite the fact that I can run the script with `./mpi_script.sh`

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was I didn't have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Adding [`#!/usr/bin/env bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/104264) to the top of my script fixed it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# rest of script
# ...
```

N.b. be sure that the file has execute permissions:

```
chmod +x mpi_script.sh
```