# How to open and close apps using bash in MacOS

Tags: bash, macos

I want to open an app(.app) from a bash shell(.sh using #!/usr/bin/bash) which is located in a folder in /Applications. How do I open it?
If I can open it, can I close it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting your shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (which is the [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang) way as it's portable), consider the following examples:

#### Open app:

- Utilize [`open`](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) command with the `-a` option. For instance:

  ```
  open -a "Safari"
  ```
- Or, using [`osascript`](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) to execute an AppleScript. For instance:

  ```
  osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate'
  ```

  Or a terse equivalent:

  ```
  osascript -e 'activate app "Safari"'
  ```

#### Close app:

- Utilize `osascript` to execute an AppleScript. For instance:

  ```
  osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to quit'
  ```

  Or a terse equivalent:

  ```
  osascript -e 'quit app "Safari"'
  ```

**Note:** If `bash` actually resides in `/usr/bin/` on macOS as per your question the above examples will work successfully with the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/bash`

Comment: Is osascript better or open better?

Comment: Aaron, in terms of _"better"_ there's really little difference between the two given your requirement - both achieve the desired result on macOS. If I had to make a choice, I would probably choose to use `osascript -e 'activate app "Safari"'` and `osascript -e 'quit app "Safari"'`, simply because of the similarity of syntax for both opening and closing - and perhaps because of its marginal improved readability. That being said, `open` doesn't have to call _AppleScript_ which inevitably results in a _very minor_ performance gain (probably microseconds faster)... Toss a coin ;)

Answer (score -1):

**of course you can do that, please use the terminal command "open".**

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo This is a play music script

# play Music from command line in the background
open ~/Downloads/AlanWalker-Faded.m4a & 

# wait some seconds 
sleep 60 

# force quit iTunes 
killall iTunes
```

Comment: Sorry, but this opens a music file, which just opens the default music app(iTunes in this case)