# Defining & calling mulitiple items in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to do below:

```
cores=("N1" "N2" "N3")
echo "${cores}"
```

When I run the script I am getting below:

```
./test.sh: 3: ./test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: `cores=("N1" "N2" "N3"); echo "${cores[@]}"`

Comment: Unless you want to print them out on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.. Also I noticed I beginning the script with #!/bin/sh which Ubuntu it seems not the way. Changed it to #!/bin/bash.

Comment: @Emmanual Arrays are a bash extension, not available in all shells. In recent versions of Ubuntu, [/bin/sh is dash, a much more basic shell](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).

Comment: @Perplexabot You might want to write that as an answer

Comment: @GauravSingh, I would have but this is really a duplicate and should be flagged.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, it worked.. Also I noticed I beginning the script with `#!/bin/sh` which Ubuntu it seems not the way. Changed it to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: "Thanks, it worked" is not an answer. You should write what you did instead.

Comment: Also see [What is the preferred Bash shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206/608639)