# Vim wrong syntax highlighting in bash script

Tags: bash, vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm new to vim and bash and something seems odd to me. I have two functions and they have a different highlighting, but I can't understand why. I searched through google, but I haven't found an answer to this specific problem.

Here's how the code looks like with syntax highlighting:

[image: Functions]

```
function unlock() {
    rm -f ${LOCKFILE}
    if [ -f ${LOCKFILE} ]; then
        echo "ERROR: Unable to delete lockfile ${LOCKFILE}!"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo_debug "lock file ${LOCKFILE} removed."
}

function copy_file() {
        #  scp -q -i "$RSA_FILE" -P "$NEXTCLOUD_SERVER_PORT" "$1" \
        #     "$NEXTCLOUD_SERVER_USER@$NEXTCLOUD_SERVER_HOST:$NEXTCLOUD_SERVER_DEST_DIR"
        echo "copy_file()"
}
```

I noticed that if I add another function named `coFUNCTION()` the highlighting changes to the one like `copy_file()`. Why is this the case?

Here's my .vimrc

```
1 set number
2 syntax on
3 :color desert
```

Comment: Can you try running `:syntax sync fromstart`?
BTW, on my system, the highlighting is seen fine.

Comment: ran then command, but nothing changed.

Comment: What is the file type detected? Use :set filetype?.. good to enable the ft plugin "set filetype=on"

Comment: @SamDaniel, Actually, `set filetype=sh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh` != `bash`, and the `function` keyword is a bashism. So it's entirely possible the syntax highlighting is correct, except it's been applied to the wrong language. You can simply remove the `function` keyword to get closer to POSIX syntax, that might help the highlighting code. Or, depending on how the highlighting code works you might have more luck adding a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) or changing the script extension from "sh" to "bash".

Comment: Further info about useless `function` keyword here... https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete