# /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, testing, atlas

I have faced this following error while i am trying to run a software :

/afs/cern.ch/work/a/atnourji/ROOTAnalysisTutorial/build/atlas_build_run.sh: line 16: /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory

Any advise for this matter are very appreciated ?

$ nano /afs/cern.ch/work/a/atnourji/ROOTAnalysisTutorial/build/atlas_build_run.sh :

```
#!/user/bin/bash

# Transmit errors: set -e

# Set up the environment: source /afs/cern.ch/work/a/atnourji/ROOTAnalysisTutorial/build/x86_64-centos7-gcc62-opt/setup.sh || exit 1

# Run the command: exec $* || exit 1 ~
```

Comment: *Does* `/usr/bin/bash` exist? The location of your shell is different between different machines. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is generally a better alternative (searching the PATH to try to find a copy of `bash`), assuming your OS provides `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: BTW, `exec $*` is **very** buggy. You should probably be running `exec "$@"` instead.

Comment: ...to prove what I mean about `exec $*` being buggy, try running the command `printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line" '*'` through this wrapper after you fix the initial "no such file or directory" issue.

Comment: (BTW, it's also [not great practice to use file extensions on executables](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/); just name it `atlas_build_run`, and then you aren't under any obligation to rename it, and force all your users to change how they call it, if you ever rewrite it in a different language; and you also aren't falsely implying that a *bash* script is compatible with *sh*, which is a different, simpler language).

Comment: (Also, use `|| exit` instead of `|| exit 1` and you'll pass through the exact exit status of the component that failed, instead of masking that exact status and forcing it always to be `1`).

Comment: On Linux Mint, bash is '/bin/bash'. I'm sure most distro will follow, and env is /usr/bin/env

Comment: `user` != `usr`.  Check the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`#!/usr/bin/env bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) as the shebang (disclaimer: my answer). /user with an "e" is not a standard *nix path.

Comment: The error message they copied-and-pasted using `usr` implies that `user` was a typo in asking the question, vs part of their actual usage. Thus, this looks like a `/bin/bash`-vs-`/usr/bin/bash` issue, vs a `/user`-vs-`/usr` issue.