# Get the name of the folder from a path with whitespace

Tags: bash, directory, path, basename

I'm new to bash and I'd like to know how to print the last folder name from a path.

```
mypath="/Users/ckull/Desktop/Winchester stuff/a b c/some other folder/"
dir="$(basename $mypath)"
echo "looking in $dir"
```

Where *dir* is the last directory in the path. It should print as

```
some other folder
```

Instead I get:

```
Winchester
stuff
a
b
c
some
other
folder
```

I understand that spaces are causing problems ;) Do I need to pipe the result to a string and then replace newlines? Or perhaps a better way...

Comment: I get an error message: "basename: extra operand ‘b’". So try `dir="$(basename "$mypath")"`

Comment: *Always* quote parameter expressions. Always. The cases where doing so is wrong is *vastly* outnumbered by the cases where it is necessary or irrelevant; quoting will save you a lot of time debugging.

Comment: Copy/paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) (add a [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang) on the first line before it, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) and it will indicate what the issue is.

Comment: I had #! /bin/bash down as the shebang. Which one is right? or is that another SO question ;)

Comment: It's already been asked. Click the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When dealing with whitespaces, all variables should be **double-quoted** when passed as command line arguments, so bash would know to treat them as a single parameter:

```
mypath="/Users/ckull/Desktop/Winchester stuff/a b c/some other folder/"
dir="$(basename "$mypath")" # quote also around $mypath!
echo "lookig in $dir"
# examples
ls "$dir" # quote only around $dir!
cp "$dir/a.txt" "$dir/b.txt"
```

This is how variable expansion occurs in bash:

```
var="aaa bbb"
               # args: 0      1              2     3
foo $var ccc   # ==>   "foo"  "aaa"          "bbb" "ccc"
foo "$var" ccc # ==>   "foo"  "aaa bbb"      "ccc"
foo "$var ccc" # ==>   "foo"  "aaa bbb ccc"
```