# Bash post increment aborts script execution

Tags: linux, bash

Running with `bash -e`:

```
round=0
((round++))
echo "Done"
```

Will not show `Done`. Why? How can I use post-increment when `-e` is set?

Comment: I believe `((expr))` is a Bash-ism. You need to use Bash as the interpreter. Add the shebang. See [What is the preferred Bash shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206/608639) Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: This is one of many ways that `set -e` can have weird effects. See [BashFAQ #105: Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look of some examples:

```
round=0
((round++))
echo $?

round=1
((round-1))
echo $?

((0))
echo $?
```

In all cases `$?` returns 1.

`Bash` manpage states:

> ((expression))
>         The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below  under
>         **ARITHMETIC  EVALUATION.**   If the value of the expression is non-zero, the
>         return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.   This  is  exactly
>                 equivalent to let "expression".

If the `-e` option is set, then the script exits because:

> -e
>       Exit  immediately  if a pipeline (which may
>       consist of  a  single  simple  command),  a
>       list,  or  a  compound  command  (see SHELL
>       GRAMMAR above), exits with a non-zero  status. ...

You can avoid the termination by assigning a variable to the result of arithmetic evaluation:

```
set -e
round=0
dummy=$((round++))
echo "Done"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to invent a dummy variable. Just write it as `: $((round++))`, since `:` returns 0 exit status.

Comment: @IlyaG That doesn't update the `round` variable, and will also exit with an error if `round` happens to be -1.