# Error when starting node app via bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, cron, shebang

i have an node-app `index.js` at `/home/pi/apps/index.js`

my bash script: `script.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
node /home/pi/apps/index.js
```

I want to use this bash script to run it as cron job but it already crashes when executing `./script.sh`

```
ReferenceError: node is not defined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace `#!/usr/bin/env node` with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Or [`#!/usr/bin/env bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588).