# How to run a bash script multiple times with same output?

Tags: bash, unix

This seems like a weird question to have, but I need to write a simple bash script that takes two arguments from the command line. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts a:b: flag; do
    case "${flag}" in 
        a) optionA="${OPTARG}";;
        b) optionB="${OPTARG}";;
    esac
done

echo $optionA
echo $optionB
```

When I run `. script.sh -a optionA -b optionB` it works exactly as expected and echos the two inputs. The issue is if I run the exact same script again, the arguments are not echoed and I just see two blank lines. Only the first time running it produces the correct behavior. If I close the terminal session and try again it works, but I'd like to be able to run it several times in a row.

I was thinking the issue had something to do with the variables remaining and then being overwritten by the next run so I tried something like `unset optionA`, but it did not help.

I apologize if this is a simple question, but I could not seem to find an answer anywhere else and I would much appreciate any help. Thanks!

EDIT: The simple solution is that I was sourcing the script when I could have been running it. Using `bash test.sh -a optionA -b optionB` works just fine.

EDIT 2: If there is a need to source instead of run, the answer Charles gave also works; use `unset OPTIND` after each run.

Comment: _Sourcing_ a script and _running_ the script are quite different things.

Comment: ...because you're sourcing the script, `OPTARG` and `OPTIDX` are left in place between runs.

Comment: That said, I can't reproduce this -- works fine. As it should: `optionA` is left in place after your first run, so even if the `while getopts` doesn't do anything on your second run, `echo $optionA` still prints the option parsed during the initial invocation. If you have a _real_ reproducer that causes the problem, please make sure the [mre] in the question still does likewise.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense! I knew I had to be doing something dumb. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See the code at http://ix.io/3sem re: how I tested this for the "works fine" assertion -- try plugging that into https://replit.com/languages/bash

Comment: (pardon above, wrote `OPTIDX` before checking the actual name; it should be `OPTIND`).

Comment: Yeah the example I included in the question does the same thing where it doesn't echo after the first run. Not sure why that would be, but for my purposes running the script is sufficient anyway.

Comment: BTW, if you're not happy with the answers added and want to add your own, use the "Add an Answer" button to do that instead of editing an answer into the question itself.

Comment: That shebang line looks off, it should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#~/bin/bash` (or, [arguably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206/3266847), `#!/usr/bin/env bash`)

Comment: (See also [What to do when OP answers his/her own question in an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit) over on [meta])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset getopts between sourced invocations of your script, `unset OPTIND`.

This variable tells getopts how many items have already been processed, and thus how many should be skipped.

---

By contrast, if you just run your script without sourcing it, this variable won't be held over, so there's nothing to reset.

Comment: Amazing, this is just the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you consider the question solved, click the checkbox next to the answer. Otherwise, feel free to add your own answer and accept that when allowed.