# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - hook not working exec format error

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

I'm trying to add a predeploy hook for AWS Beanstalk.

The file is

```
+-- .platform
    +-- hooks
        +-- predeploy
            +-- 01_npm_install_and_build.sh
```

With the following contents:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum -y install nodejs
cd /var/app/current/
sudo npm install
sudo npm run build
```

I've tested the code works by SSHing to the instance and running `sh 01_npm_install_and_build.sh`

by looking at the log file `tail -f /var/log/eb-engine.log`

I also tried `postdeploy` with the same issue, here's that error:

> [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] -
> [RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks]. Stop running the command. Error:
> Command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_npm_install_and_build.sh failed
> with error fork/exec
> .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_npm_install_and_build.sh: exec format
> error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing a "shebang" at the top of the sh script.

The sh script should start with:
`#!/bin/bash`... or see [What is the preferred Bash shebang ("#!")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang) to check which shebang you should be using. `which sh` should give you an idea.

Furthermore. `/var/app/current/` isn't available at predeploy, so use `/var/app/staging/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it is because I created a file in Windows, which is saved with UTF-8 with BOM.
I solved my case by saving it with encoding UTF-8 (**without** BOM) instead.

[image]